# Backup iPhone pictures that are not using local storage but iCloud

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, data-synchronization, photos.app

Until 2017 I took pictures with mi iPhone using local storage, and then I saved them to my Macbook using Photo.app. But since 2018, I started to use on the iPhone the option to store pictures on iCloud. Since then I did not use  Photo.app backup and now I want to do it.

I wonder if I will have some sort of problem since on my iPhone and using local storage I do not have all copies of my pictures, but they are all supposed to be on iCloud. How should I do this so that I am sure that all new pictures are transferred to Photos.app?

Comment: What can be the problem in turning on iCloud on laptop? maybe the macOS  library would need to be deleted. So that new can be set up which will download photos from iCloud.

Comment: I do not want my macOS local library to be deleted, since there I have very old pictures taken with other cameras

Comment: Oh so you have X photos only on Mac, Y on iPhone and iCloud. And you want X and Y everywhere.

Comment: yes, that is what I need. And of course I do not want any of them to be deleted.